# pg node (postgres) UPDATE statement returns column does not exist when it does exist

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, node-postgres

In pgAdmin/the cli, the following query:

```sql
UPDATE wq SET l_id = NULL, v_id = NULL WHERE w_id = 'cf93bc71-88c1-4bba-9e5c-fdc58d0ed14e';
```

works fine. However, when calling the same with the `pg` package in `node`:

```js
const w_id_val = 'cf93bc71-88c1-4bba-9e5c-fdc58d0ed14e';
/*
(here client is the result of calling const pool = pg.Pool({...}) , 
then let client = await pool.connect());
*/
const result = await client.query(
  `UPDATE wq
   SET l_id = null,
       v_id = null
   WHERE w_id = $1`,
  [w_id_val]
);
```

I get the following error:

```json
{
   "message":"column \"w_id\" does not exist",
   "stack":"error: column \"w_id\" does not exist\n    at Connection.parseE (/Users/lukasjenks/Documents/Work/socrative-nodejs/node_modules/pg/lib/connection.js:569:11)\n    at Connection.parseMessage (/Users/lukasjenks/Documents/Work/socrative-nodejs/node_modules/pg/lib/connection.js:396:17)\n    at Socket.<anonymous> (/Users/lukasjenks/Documents/Work/socrative-nodejs/node_modules/pg/lib/connection.js:132:22)\n    at Socket.emit (events.js:314:20)\n    at Socket.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:483:12)\n    at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:297:12)\n    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:272:9)\n    at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:213:10)\n    at TCP.onStreamRead (internal/stream_base_commons.js:188:23)\n    at TCP.callbackTrampoline (internal/async_hooks.js:126:14)",
   "name":"error",
   "length":112,
   "severity":"ERROR",
   "code":"42703",
   "position":"68",
   "file":"parse_relation.c",
   "line":"3514",
   "routine":"errMissingColumn"
}
```

I can confirm the column exists with this query:

```sql
SELECT table_schema, table_name, column_name, data_type
  FROM information_schema.columns
 WHERE table_name = 'wq';
```

```
public  wq  id  uuid
public  wq  w_id    uuid
public  wq  l_id    uuid
public  wq  v_id    uuid
```

I can also confirm that the column (w_id) should be recognized by `pg` as when using `pg` to query the table with a `SELECT` statement, I get this back in the `fields` property in the result object returned:

```json
  fields: [
    Field {
      name: 'id',
      tableID: 26611,
      columnID: 1,
      dataTypeID: 2950,
      dataTypeSize: 16,
      dataTypeModifier: -1,
      format: 'text'
    },
    Field {
      name: 'w_id',
      tableID: 26611,
      columnID: 3,
      dataTypeID: 2950,
      dataTypeSize: 16,
      dataTypeModifier: -1,
      format: 'text'
    },
    ...
```

I've also confirmed this isn't a case issue; i.e. the column name is all lowercase and using double quotes around the column name has no effect.

Comment: Are you sure you connected to the correct database with the correct role?

Comment: This `"column \"w_id\" does not exist"` says something in the code is passing in `"w_id"` where it shouldn't. This generally happens when there is a double quoted string being passed in as a value e.g. `select "w_id"::text; ERROR:  column "w_id" does not exist`. I would look at the Postgres log to get more detail.

Comment: @Bergi Thanks for your comment. Yes, because as in the output above when I use .query() to SELECT from the table from the app in the same place as the update statement, the column exists.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver that's how Postgres reports invalid column names. It doesn't mean it was passed as text in the query

Comment: This `public  wq  w_id    uuid` does not match this `name: 'w_id', ... format: 'text'`. So either `pg` is getting the types wrong or you are looking at a different table. Again look at the Postgres log to see what is actually hitting the database.